# The use of the verb "hurry" in context

Tags: word-usage

Tell me please if the following use of the verb *hurry* is correct.

> You had not better squat that fast, because when you hurry doing it, you could get injured.

Comment: It's "correct", but not particularly idiomatic today - see this NGram for [*if you hurry it / if you rush it*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if+you+hurry+it%2Cif+you+rush+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cif%20you%20hurry%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20you%20rush%20it%3B%2Cc0). Note that *to hurry [something] **along*** is quite natural (much more so than ***rush** it along*), but that usually means *to make something [else] move more quickly*, not *to act / do something / move oneself more quickly*.

Comment: ...That's to say, I think your sentence would be more natural if you discard ***doing***. And also ***it***, perhaps - it's not really necessary in this context.

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct.

The correct sentence would be:

> You **had better not** squat that fast, because when you **do it quickly** you could get injured.

The suitable word would be *quickly*. *Had not better* is also not correct. The comma is also not needed.